# Sumar todas las transacciones de inventario Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy creando un sistema de inventario, en el cual poseeo los 2 siguientes modelos:

**Modelo Producto**

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :price
      t.integer :weight
      t.string :unity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Modelo Transacciones de Inventario**
Este registra la cantidad de items a ingresar o a egresar del inventario por cada producto, para esto he agregado un campo booleano, que determinara el tipo de transaccion, ya sea compra o venta

```
class CreateInventoryTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :inventory_transactions do |t|
      t.string :invoice
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :quantity
      t.boolean :transaction_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

En este caso he realizado una transaccion de compra de 100 items de un mismo producto, pero a la hora de intentar imprimir ese dato de ese producto en el loop, me genera un error, y obvio dado que ese producto posee muchas transacciones de compra o venta, ¿de que forma podria imprimir la suma de transacciones de compra, o de venta dentro del loop, para cada producto?

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.weight %></td>
    <td><%= product.unity %></td>
    <td><%= product.inventory_transactions.quantity %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Evitando el error de: `undefined method 'quantity' for #<InventoryTransaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fdc3d68c038>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás llamando el método `quantity` sobre una colección, no en un objeto `Product`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es primer sumar las cantidades de cada transacción para después mostrarlas; por ejemplo:

```
product.inventory_transactions.sum(&:quantity)
```

Aunque puedes utilizarlo así directamente en tu vista, te recomiendo extraer esa lógica y agregarla en el modelo `Product`:

```
class Product
  # ...

  def inventory_transactions_quantity
    inventory_transactions.sum(&:quantity)
  end
end
```

Y en tu vista puedes llamar el nuevo método:

```
product.inventory_transactions_quantity
```

---

> ...al realizar una transacción lo especifico por medio de un campo *booleano* es decir, `transaction_type`, ¿de qué forma podría restar la cantidad de datos de compra, es decir que tengan `transaction_type: true`, menos la cantidad de `transaction_type: false`?

Podrías agregar un método (privado) en tu modelo para sumar los valores de `quantity` para cada `transaction_type` y luego utilizarlo en tu método actual para obtener la diferencia; por ejemplo:

```
# app/models/product.rb

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def inventory_transactions_quantity
    transactions_type_quantity(true) - transactions_type_quantity(false)
  end

  private
  def transactions_type_quantity(type)
    inventory_transactions.where(transaction_type: type).sum(&:quantity)
  end
end
```

Como ejercicio para mejorar a este código, podrías considerar utilizar *scopes* en el modelo `InventoryTransaction` para evitar el uso de `where` dentro del modelo `Product`.

Comment: Tremendo Gerry! Me ha venido fenomenal! Una consulta mas Gerry, al realizar una transaccion lo especifico por medio de un campo booleano es decir, transaction_type, de que forma podria restar la cantidad de datos de compra es decir que tengan transacrion_type: true, menos la cantidad de transaction_type: false? Para saar el numero de existencias de ese producto

Comment: @HectorHernandez Revisa nuevamente la respuesta, agregué un ejemplo que puede servirte/guiarte para obtener el dato que buscas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Gerry! Va fenomenal! Agradezco mucho tu tiempo! Saludos!

Comment: Saludos Gerry, una consulta, actualmente he pasado precio, a InventoryTransaction, por lo que por cada compra que se realize, se agregara su precio, ahora bien, quiero mostrar esto en la vista de productos, por lo que he hecho lo siguiente para calcular el precio de cada item, tomando en cuenta que si se realizaron 10 compras de un mismo producto, se deberan sumar los precios de cada compra de ese producto, y promediarlo, algo como:

´def price
self.inputs.where(self.id == self.inputs.ids).pluck(:price).sum / self.inputs.where(self.id == self.inputs.ids).size
end´

Comment: Sin embargo me da el error: 
ZeroDivisionError in Products#index 
divided by 0

Comment: @HectorHernandez No tengo suficientes elementos para poder darte una respuesta; ¿podrías abrir una pregunta nueva incluyendo el código de los modelos relacionados?

Comment: Saludos Gerry, he logrado mas o menos solucionar el problema podemos decirlo, asi, sin embargo aprovechando el mismo problema, he abierto una pregunta, en la que tengo que tocar 2 factores para calcular el precio y la existencia del mismo, agradezco, pudieras orientarme, Gerry, te comparto la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179744/calcular-existencias-por-la-cantidad-de-items-entre-su-contenido-rails